# multitouch gestures in GNOME-Shell

Tags: 12.10, gnome, multi-touch

I switched from Unity to GNOME, and I really miss the gestures on Unity (3 fingers window moving, expand to maximize, etc).

I have two finger scrolling and two finger tap to right click out of the box on GNOME, but is there any way to configure these additional gestures? Thanks!

Ubuntu 12.10 64 bit,
ASUS N56VZ

Answer (score 0):

two-finger gestures works only for wacom touchscreens as it is supported by driver...
for any other touchscreens with evdev driver there is no any 2-finger gestures in Gnome too :(

Comment: I think the question related to multi-touch touchpads, rather than touch_screens_.